# Node, update view after save to database

Tags: node.js, view

I'm new to node.js and I'm trying to update the view after database save, should I use vue/react to do that?

**EDIT:**

I have my bin/www file;

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('demo:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);



/**
* Socket.io
**/
var io = app.io;
io.listen(server);


/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

then my app.js file;

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
var https = require('https');
var socket_io = require('socket.io');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//Socket setup
var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;

var index = require('./routes/index')(io);

// io.on('connection', function(socket){
//   console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
//   //io.sockets.emit('data', socket.id);
// });

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap

app.use('/', index);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

my index.js file;

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var cron = require('node-cron');
    var apiCalls = require('../apiCalls');

    var livedata = [];

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
        io.sockets.emit('data', socket.id);
        io.sockets.emit('data', livedata);
    });


    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
         res.render('index', { title: 'demo', data: 'yey!' });      
    });




    var cronJob = cron.schedule('*/3 * * * * *', function(){
      apiCalls.getData(function(data){
        livedata.push(data);
        console.log(data);

      });

    }); 
    cronJob.start();

    var empty_arr = cron.schedule('*/11 * * * * *', function(){
        livedata = [];
    }); 
    empty_arr.start();


    return router;
}
```

I'm trying to make an api call with the cron job which works fine. I would like to update the view every second by using socket io. This works fine as well. When I load localhost:8000 the socket prints made connection to the console.

I'm trying to combine these 2. As I'm a starter in learning node.js, I came with the idea of pushing the data to an array then call that array from the socket.io.

Then I empty array every 11 seconds. The thing is, to be able to see the data I'm still have to refresh the page. My understanding is that, if I have to refresh the page to see the data why to use socket.io.

I think I'm doing something wrong that I expect it to be refreshed automatically.

Thank you.

Comment: To do that, you can use any server side (Node.js, PHP, ...). It depends of your real needs, and database technologies.

Comment: I'm using mongo, node and express. After save I want to manipulate the dom, I think I can use jquery as well. Just could not understand how to combine

Comment: You would either use some sort of polling from the client (eg. http get a path until it returns a new item) or you can use WebSockets with a module such as [socket.io](https://socket.io) which is more efficient and will show changes faster.

Comment: I have implemented an web socket, but I think my understanding is different. I'm editing the question to put my code in it